# How to read text file and save last x lines - one line in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I made it work on two lines.

- How would the code look like on one line only? In ruby.
- Is the code for last x lines (55 in this case) the best?

code sample

```
$max_lines_in_log=55
$cron_log = "C:/EduTester/cron/rufus.log"


array = File.read($cron_log).split("\n")[-$max_lines_in_log,$max_lines_in_log]
open($cron_log, 'w') { |f| f.puts array.join("\n") }
```

Comment: Do you have a shortage of newline characters at your workplace?

Comment: I don't understand your question....

Comment: It's humor. I can only assume that, because you need this on one line, there's some sort of shortage. Otherwise, it doesn't really matter how many lines it takes (up to a point - obviously, if you end up with a 6000-line behemoth, you're probably doing something wrong).

Comment: I thought you were referring to `("\n")` in my code .... I always learn from answers on SO .... so I create questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
`tail -n #{$max_lines_in_log} #{$cron_log} > #{$cron_log}`
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate writing it in one line but it's what you asked:

```
File.open("o_f.log", "w") { |o_f| o_f.write File.open("i_f.log") { |i_f| i_f.each_line.each_cons(55).inject{ |a, e| e } } }
```

Doesn't work if `nlines < 55` though, so slightly better version would be:

```
File.open("o_f.log", "w") { |o_f| o_f.write File.open("i_f.log") { |i_f| i_f.each_line.inject([]){ |ls, l| ls.shift(54).unshift(l) }.reverse } }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File.open(output, 'w'){|out| out.puts File.open(input).readlines[-55,55]}
```

Comment: There is a small problem here, the one I tried to avoid in my answer. You are going to have to load whole file into memory, and logs can be pretty big.

Comment: Not my log :-) also because this "cleaning" code will run at least once a day.

Comment: Input & output file are the same in my case. Your code doesn't work as it overwrites the file with a string `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
buff=[]
IO.foreach('c:/test.txt') { |line|
  if buff.length < n
    buff << line
  else
    buff.shift
    buff << line
  end
}

result = buff.join
```